# R version of Vlookup with multiple matches per cell

Tags: r, match, vlookup

I have a vector with numbers and a lookup table. I want the numbers replaced by the description from the lookup table.

This is easy when vectors are straight forward like this example:

```
> variable <- sample(1:5, 10, replace=T)
> variable
 [1] 5 4 5 3 2 3 2 3 5 2
> 
> lookup <- data.frame(var = 1:5, description=LETTERS[1:5])
> lookup
  var description
1   1           A
2   2           B
3   3           C
4   4           D
5   5           E
> 
> with(lookup, description[match(variable, var)])
 [1] E D E C B C B C E B
Levels: A B C D E
```

However, when single elements of a vector contain multiple outcomes, I get in trouble:

```
variable <- c("1", "2^3", "1^5", "4", "4")
```

I would like the vector returned to give:

```
c("A", "B^C", "A^E", "D", "D")
```

Comment: You aren't looking for a simple vlookup (often done as a "merge" or "join" in R/Python), since you want sub-string matches. I suggest you look into splitting your complex-`variable` entries into individuals, merge/join/vlookup, then re-combine.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, there are a couple of steps needed to achieve the desired output.  The following splits your variable, indexes the results against the description variable and then uses paste to collapse multiple elements.

```
sapply(strsplit(variable, "\\^"), function(x) paste0(lookup$description[as.numeric(x)], collapse = "^"))
[1] "A"   "B^C" "A^E" "D"   "D"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one character match and replacement you can use `chartr`

```
chartr(paste0(lookup$var, collapse = ""), 
       paste0(lookup$description, collapse = ""), variable)

#[1] "A"   "B^C" "A^E" "D"   "D"
```

`chartr` basically tells that replace

```
paste0(lookup$var, collapse = "")
#[1] "12345"
```

with

```
paste0(lookup$description, collapse = "")
#[1] "ABCDE"
```

It is also useful since it does not change or return `NA` for characters which do not match.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scan` to parse text into numeric, which can then be used as an index to pick items which can then be collapsed together. Add quiet=TRUE to suppress  "Read" messages.

```
sapply(variable, function(t) { 
              paste( lookup$description[ scan(text=t, sep="^")], collapse="^")} )

Read 1 item
Read 2 items
Read 2 items
Read 1 item
Read 1 item
    1   2^3   1^5     4     4 
  "A" "B^C" "A^E"   "D"   "D"
```